# proof or disproof of thm

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

Looking for proof or disproof of

Given some parameterized non-convex compositive objective $L(y, f(x;\theta))$ which has some global minimum $\theta^*$, there exists a function $R$ s.t. $R(y, f(x;\theta))$ is convex and also has a minimum at $\theta^*$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: This does not make sense. What are $y,f,x$? Fixed? If yes, then the convex envelop of $L$ will do the job.

Comment: every constant function fulfills this..